# Exception ItemNotString not caught with assertRaises

Tags: python, unit-testing

```
import unittest
import filterList

class TestFilterList(unittest.TestCase):
    """ docstring for TestFilterList
    """

    def setUp(self):
        self._filterby = 'B'


    def test_checkListItem(self):
        self.flObj = filterList.FilterList(['hello', 'Boy', 1], self._filterby)
        self.assertRaises(filterList.ItemNotString, self.flObj.checkListItem)


    def test_filterList(self):
        self.flObj = filterList.FilterList(['hello', 'Boy'], self._filterby)
        self.assertEquals(['Boy'], self.flObj.filterList())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

My above test `test_checkListItem()` fails , for the below `filterList` module:

```
import sys
import ast

class ItemNotString(Exception):
    pass


class FilterList(object):
    """docstring for FilterList
    """

    def __init__(self, lst, filterby):
        super(FilterList, self).__init__()
        self.lst = lst
        self._filter = filterby
        self.checkListItem()

    def checkListItem(self):
        for index, item in enumerate(self.lst):
            if type(item) == str:
                continue
            else:
                raise ItemNotString("%i item '%s' is not of type string" % (index+1, item))
        print self.filterList()
        return True

    def filterList(self):
        filteredList = []
        for eachItem in self.lst:
            if eachItem.startswith(self._filter):
                filteredList.append(eachItem)
        return filteredList


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        filterby = sys.argv[2]
    except IndexError:
        filterby = 'H'
    flObj = FilterList(ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1]), filterby)
    #flObj.checkListItem()
```

Why does the test fail with the error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_checkListItem (__main__.TestFilterList)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_filterList.py", line 13, in test_checkListItem
    self.flObj = filterList.FilterList(['hello', 'Boy', 1], self._filterby)
  File "/Users/sanjeevkumar/Development/python/filterList.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.checkListItem()
  File "/Users/sanjeevkumar/Development/python/filterList.py", line 23, in checkListItem
    raise ItemNotString("%i item '%s' is not of type string" % (index+1, item))
ItemNotString: 3 item '1' is not of type string

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Also, is the approach of the `filterList` module correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is not being caught by your `assertRaises` call because it's being raised on the previous line. If you look carefully at the traceback, you'll see that the `checkListItem` was called by the `FilterList` class's `__init__` method, which in turn was called when you try to create `self.flObj` in your test.

Comment: in that case what should I do so that I do not have to remove the call to `self.checkListItem()` from `__init__`

Comment: @san You can probably wrap your `assertRaises` call around the object creation, instead. I'm not sure exactly what the syntax is, but it shouldn't be too complicated.